# Is possible to modify exponential function to get values [1, A] from domain [0, B]

Tags: python, math, discrete-mathematics

I have a math problem... I want to get saturation function which works like that:

[image: Illustrative figure]

I tried with the following code:

```
def sat_f(x, A, B, base=1.5):
   y = np.power(base, x)
   y_max = np.power(base, B)
   norm_coeff = A / y_max
   y = norm_coeff * y
   return y
```

But I have problem to get f(0) = 1 when it's scaled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a python guy, but mathematically what you need is:

`f(x) = A^(x/B)`

This will give you:

f(0) = 1

f(B) = A

and in-between range the function will grow exponentially w.r.t A

hope this helps

Comment: Helps a lot, thanks. How can I control the "exponential slope"?

Comment: You an pump-up the exponent part with another function, something that increases but reaches 1 at B. One such functions are trigonometric ones, like sine.  f(x) = A^( x * Sin( pi * x / (2B) ) / B) is an example. You can choose any other function in conjunction with x/B as long as it reaches 1 when x = B

Answer (score 1):

As ram adhikari said in his answer the formula is `f(x) = A^(x/B)`.

Python code is a one-liner:

```
def sat_f(x, A, B):
   return np.power(A, x/B)
```

Running code and a plot can be found [here](http://tpcg.io/_3MUWXV)